# Calling Console Application (.exe) in Event Receiver and Getting Error

Tags: sharepoint, process, ocr, eventreceiver

I am using SharePoint foundation. I have a console application that is used to run some OCR process. I am calling the exe of the console application from windows service and it is working fine. I am trying to call the same exe from an event receiver but unable to call the exe and getting some error. The Event receiver is working fine but unable to call exe. I have tried to call the other exes like notepad.exe but getting same error. The details are below:

**Code:**

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{

   try
   {
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
       Log("Event Occured.");
       string OCRedText = string.Empty;
       string Listname = properties.ListTitle;
       string itemName = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Name"]);
       string itemTitle = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Title"]);

       callService(); // Here is the method to call Process                

       SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
       if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(myLock, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)))
       {
           if (Convert.ToString(item["OCRed"]) == "False")
           {                       
               item["OCRed"] = "True";
               Thread.Sleep(10000);
               item.SystemUpdate();
               Log("Item Added and Updated.");
           }
           else
           {
               Log("Can not update the Item.");
           }
       }
       Log("Event End."+"\r\n");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Log("Error in Item Added Event Receiver.");
       Log(ex.ToString());               
   }
}

public void callService()
{
    Log("Calling Service is not easy.");
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo pinfoService = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pinfoService.FileName = @"D:\Khan\khan.exe";
        //pinfoService.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
        pinfoService.UseShellExecute = false;
        pinfoService.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pinfoService.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pinfoService.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pinfoService.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pinfoService.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Log("FileName: " + pinfoService.FileName);
        Log("Arguments for callService : "+pinfoService.Arguments);
        Process pService = new Process();

        pService.StartInfo = pinfoService;
        Log("Process Before Start.");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        pService.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Log("Process Before wait for exit.");
        pService.WaitForExit();
        Log("Process Completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Error in callService(). Please contact your Administrator.");
        Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**and below is the error I am getting on `pService.Start();`**

```
=========================================

Info : Process Before Start.

Info : Error in callService(). Please contact your Administrator.

Info : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Not enough quota is available to process this command

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

   at OCRonUploadDoc.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1.callService()

=========================================
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. Please help me...!!!

Thanks in Advance.

- Khan Abubakar

Answer (score 0):

I think that the asp.net account under which the application pool runs does not have permissions to start the exe file. You can check this out http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/386380/cannot-run-exe-files-in-asp.net-application 
However if your system will be used by more users you can run into problems really quickly, because every change of a document will spawn a new process. The server will run out of ram and the farm will not be unavailable.